# MYSQL connection error in Google Cloud SQL with a React Application

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine

My React based MERN app runs on Google App engine. This also has a MYSQL connection which was working fine on localhost (XAMPP MYSQL Database).
I created a SQL instance on Google Cloud and have the Instance Connection Name. But I am getting unable to connect errors.

```
    Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'MyGoogleProject-1537065009201:asia-south1:MyProj',
  host: 'MyGoogleProject-1537065009201:asia-south1:MyProj',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

Here is my application code that was working on Local. Below is my env.js

```
  "MYSQL_HOST": "localhost",
  "MYSQL_USER": "GoogleDBUser",
  "MYSQL_PASSWORD": "GoogleDBPassword",
  "MYSQL_DATABASE": "GoogleDB1",
```

Here is code for MYSQL connection:

```
// RETUNS MYSQL DATABASE
const mysql = require('mysql'),
  { error } = require('handy-log'),
  { MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE } = process.env

const options = {
  user: MYSQL_USER,
  password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: MYSQL_DATABASE,
}

options.socketPath = `/cloudsql/<Instance_Conn_Name>`

const db = mysql.createConnection(options)

module.exports = db
```

What else is needed to connect to the Google MYSQL ? I dont know where in the above code to add the Google SQL Instance name.

Is there any other code that needs to be added above that is different from normal Xamp MYSQL when I use Google Cloud SQL instead ?

Comment: When you say your react app has a mysql connection do you mean your front end has a database connection? Cause that would be a big no no

Comment: @Dominik - No, its a MERN application (Where M is MYSQl). So it is the server that has DB connection. I will edit question to say `react based application`

Comment: yeah cool ok. So the server connects to your database and you expose an API (REST or GraphQL or whatever)... So is your servers IP whitelisted?

Comment: @Dominik - yes - above is a piece of server code.  I see in the Authorization tab - `All apps in this project are authorized by default. ` - The MYSQL DB and App are in the same project so I thought it has access to the DB. My first time on Google Cloud so I may be missing something. Is the `hostname` correct or should it be something else ?

Comment: `localhost` strikes me as odd. You would probably need either `127.0.0.1` or the actual IP of the service. Sorry I haven't worked with google services like that either...

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-sql doesn't seem to mention any addresses... maybe this helps: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip

Comment: @Dominik Thank you - Above link seems to be for local machine connection. I am trying your suggestion to use instance IP.

Comment: @Dominik using IP of the SQL instance also did not work - The error changed from `ENOTFOUND` to `ETIMEDOUT`

Answer (score 0):

You are not building the connection appropriately. You need to use the /cloudsql/ connection string format. This is required when connecting from App Engine to Cloud SQL. Take a look at the [tutorial code class](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/2-structured-data/books/model-cloudsql.js) lines 20 to 30:

```
const options = {
  user: config.get('MYSQL_USER'),
  password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
  database: 'bookshelf'
};

if (config.get('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME') && config.get('NODE_ENV') === 'production') {
  options.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${config.get('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')}`;
}

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);
```

I suggest taking a look at the full [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) documentation to have a better understanding of Cloud SQL - NodeJs.

There is another approach where you can authorize all IP addresses to connect to Cloud SQL (will still require username and password) by adding 0.0.0.0/0 to [authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add) and using the MySQL public instance IP address in your HOST param code. You cannot authorize a specific App Engine IP because they change from time to time “App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application.” as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) . This is not a recommended approach since anyone can send connection request to your instance (although they will still require username,password, db name etc).

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code as shown in my updated question based on your answer but get - `Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<InstanceConnName`

Comment: Okay so you are now using the /cloudsql/, in that case, can you confirm you added the beta_settings in yaml file? As described at [1]  "Configuring Settings" 
[1] https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql#configuring_settings

Comment: If you did add the beta_settings, is there any chance you can try the tutorial but using the current Cloud SQL instance? If you are able to, then the issue is not related to the instance but the src

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm in the exact same position. I can connect no problems from local, but when deploying to production it can't find the /cloudsql/ directory. It's like it's trying to use the proxy but it either isn't running or isn't configured. I have the beta_settings value too. So I'm stuck.